# Printing half sentence in 8086 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm

I've written this code and for some reason it only prints part of the sentence and it also doesn't assign the number from `DL` to the string and prints a 'heart' instead.

I checked in TurboDebugger and everything, beside that part, went perfectly.

I add the relevant parts:

```
.MODEL SMALL
.STACK 100h
.DATA
  ARR1   DW 333,20989,3456,2082
  ARR2   DW 333,15,5436,2082
  ARR3   DW ?
  ANSWER DB 'The last digit is: X',13,10,'$'
  TEN    DW 10
.CODE
    MOV AX,@DATA   ; DS can be written to only through a register
    MOV DS,AX      ; Set DS to point to data segment
  MAX:
    CMP AX,10
    ;MAX<10
    JL LESSTHAN10
    ;MAX>10
    MOV DX,0
    DIV TEN
    MOV ANSWER[19],DL
    JMP PRINTANSWER
  PRINTANSWER:
    MOV AH,9               ; Set print option for int 21h
    MOV DX,OFFSET ANSWER   ;  Set  DS:DX to point to answerString
    INT 21h                ;  Print DisplayString
```

Here is a screenshot of my attempt of assembling this:

[image: screen print]

Comment: Would you mind elaborating a bit more on your statement "I checked in TurboDebugger and everything, beside that part, went perfectly."

Comment: @CodeWarrior all the calculation i needed to make in the code went good and the DL got the digit 3 like i needed but when i got to assigning to the ANSWER string it assigned the 'heart' instead  of 3 and it also doesn't print the beginning of the string like i assigned it.

Comment: Try = `add dl, 48`

Comment: The reason it prints the heart is because you are moving the value 3 to DL, which is the ASCII value for the heart. You should convert it to 51 (adding 48), which will print 3.

Comment: On top of CodeWarriors comments you keep moving the result to the same location `MOV ANSWER[19],DL`

Comment: @JoseManuelAbarcaRodríguez  can't believe i forgot that part.... thank you all!

Comment: @CodeWarrior and what about the part it doesn't print the beginning of the string?

Comment: Set up memory view at `ANSWER` at the start of code, then debug... watch what happens with `ANSWER` memory, when you write values into `ARR3` .. oh, also let me greet your *relevant parts*, "hellooo". ... This *went perfectly*. :D

Answer (score 2):

> for some reason it only prints part of the sentence

This happens because you are overwriting the first 6 characters from your message *ANSWER* when you write something in the array *ARR3*.
Make sure to provide enough space for this 3rd array by writing:

```
ARR3   DW 4 dup (?)
ANSWER DB 'The last digit is: X',13,10,'$'
```

---

> it also doesn't assign the number from DL to the string and prints a 'heart' instead.

The remainder from the division by 10 gave a number from 0 to 9 that you want to print as a character. You need to actually turn it into a character first. This is done by adding 48 to it. An elegant way of doing this is by writing `add dl, "0"`.

```
DIV TEN
add dl, "0"
MOV ANSWER[19],DL
```